# boto3 - list files from sub-folder where name contains

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to list all the files in a sub-folder on `s3` with a pericular pattern in the name. The below will list all the files in the sub-folder, but I only want to list files with a particular pattern in the name.

```py
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id = 'aws_access_key_id',
                        aws_secret_access_key = 'aws_secret_access_key')

s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
prefix = 'subfolder'
pattern = 'pattern-in-file-name'

for bucket_object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix = prefix):
    print('{0}:{1}'.format(bucket.name, bucket_object.key))
```

The pattern could be prefixed with multiple options. For example, here is a list of files in s3:

```
bucket-name/subfolder/x_pattern-in-file-name.csv
bucket-name/subfolder/x_not-wanted-file.csv
bucket-name/subfolder/y_pattern-in-file-name.csv
bucket-name/subfolder/y_not-wanted-file.csv
```

and I only want to read in the below:

```
bucket-name/subfolder/x_pattern-in-file-name.csv
bucket-name/subfolder/y_pattern-in-file-name.csv
```

I figured some type of wild card would work (`bucket-name/subfolder/*_pattern-in-file-name`) for the prefix but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can achieve this just by adding `if` condition:

```
for bucket_object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix = prefix):
    if pattern in bucket_object.key:
        print('{0}:{1}'.format(bucket.name, bucket_object.key))
```